# VirtualBox Virtual Media Manager "Checking accessibility" does not stop?

Tags: virtualbox

I had a problem with my VirtualBox image where it got corrupted; this is with virtualbox 4.3.36, Ubuntu 14.04. According to some instructions I found, I tried making a new one. When I observed the new one in Virtual Media Manager, I think I started an accessibility check somehow, and then removed/released the new image (or vice versa, cannot exactly recall). The accessibility check took forever, so I think I did `kill -9` for the `VBoxXPCOMIPCD` and `VBoxSVC` processes (see below), and then did reboot the PC running VirtualBox.

After reboot, now there are no images listed in Virtual Media Manager - however, the accessibility check is *still* running (it says "Checking accessibility" with a progress bar), and doesn't look like it will complete:

[image: vboxscreen.png]

... as it's been showing the same state of the progress bar for the past 15 minutes. As you can see, all of the actions ("Copy", "Modify", etc) are greyed out. Here are the running processes while this state is shown:

```
$ ps axf | grep -v grep | grep -i 'virtu\|box'
 3418 ?        Sl     0:02          |   \_ /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox
 3434 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxXPCOMIPCD
 3440 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxSVC --auto-shutdown
```

So, does anyone know how can I stop the accessibility check in this state - or at least somehow force it to complete?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just made a new image for the (only one) virtual machine that I had, and once I did that and checked Virtual Media Manager, the "Checking accessibility" and the progress bar were gone, meaning, I guess, that the process completed successfully...